# Getting assemblies referenced by project in DiagnosticAnalyzer

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am writing code analysis which should check if our libraries are used properly. For that I need to know which assemblies are referenced by project (=analyzed document's parent project). It is possible in CodeRefactoringProviders as its context contains Document property. From document I can get to the Project and its References.

But I do not know how to get the information from CodeAnalysis contexts (SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext, ...) Is is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you register for CompilationStarted, you can get a Compilation object, and from that compilation there's a References property. You can cast those to `PortableExecutableReference` if you need file paths, or you can get symbols if you need to assert other things about them.

Comment: In the Initialize method I have registered to the CompilationStartAction. From its context one can get Compilation property as you have said, check  references and if the library you need is present, you can register to the SyntaxNodeAction (or any other needed). It works fine, thank you very much.